# Firebase do not return ascending order as expected by using orderByKey

Tags: java, android, sorting, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have some data which stored on Firebase by using **timestamp** as its key value,
but I cannot get all of them by sorting it with **orderByKey** as expected: returning value do not back in ascending order.

My JSON structure looks like:

```
{
  "1476986154" : {
    "Cons" : {
      "Black" : 91.531099,
      "Cancel" : 98.832554,
      "Happy" : 97.104925,
      "Pair" : 95.515542
    },
    "Fairy" : {
      "Apple" : {
        "Chair" : {
          "Area" : 1,
          "Count" : 96,
          "Teen" : 0.162139,
          "Score" : 95.16093
        },
        "Fake" : {
          "Area" : 3,
          "Count" : 98,
          "Teen" : 0.683259,
          "Score" : 98.249105
        }
      },
      "Dark" : {
        "Lake" : {
          "Read" : {
            "Height" : 0,
            "Width" : 0,
            "X" : 0,
            "Y" : 0
          }
        },
        "Red" : {
          "Read" : {
            "Height" : 0,
            "Width" : 0,
            "X" : 0,
            "Y" : 0
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "PhotoName" : "oo",
    "Versions" : {
      "Library" : "5.5.6.6"
    }
  },
  "1477280739" : {
    "Cons" : {
      "Black" : 96.389055,
      "Cancel" : 98.265668,
      "Happy" : 93.661556,
      "Pair" : 91.361142
    },
    "Fairy" : {
      "Apple" : {
        "Chair" : {
          "Area" : 1,
          "Count" : 100,
          "Teen" : 0.171286,
          "Score" : 90.849593
        },
        "Fake" : {
          "Area" : 3,
          "Count" : 99,
          "Teen" : 0.200965,
          "Score" : 92.367154
        }
      },
      "Dark" : {
        "Lake" : {
          "Read" : {
            "Height" : 0,
            "Width" : 0,
            "X" : 0,
            "Y" : 0
          }
        },
        "Red" : {
          "Read" : {
            "Height" : 0,
            "Width" : 0,
            "X" : 0,
            "Y" : 0
          }
        }
      },
    },
    "Name" : "pp",
    "Versions" : {
      "Library" : "5.5.6.6"
    }
  }
}
```

It returns me the largest one first(1490034200), then from smallest to second-largest value(from 1476510510 to 1488805137).
Which confused me since I need to know if the callback is going to the last now.

Code is here: I just query for last data before query for all data with same ValueEventListener:

```
DatabaseReference.orderByKey().limitToLast(recordQty).addValueEventListener(valueEventListener);
//...
DatabaseReference.orderByKey().addValueEventListener(valueEventListener);
```

Can anyone understand why this attempt not work?

---

Here's how my listener looks:

```
private class ValueEventOnChangeListener implements ValueEventListener {


        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (mDataArrayList == null) {
                mDataArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
            } else {
                mDataArrayList.clear();
            }

            getDataChange(dataSnapshot);

            if (mListener != null) {
                mListener.success(mDataArrayList);
            }
        }

        private void getDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
            try {
                if (mSubDataType == null){
                    for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                        long timestamp = Long.parseLong(data.getKey());
                        mDataArrayList.add(timestamp);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                Log.e(TAG, "onDataChange Exception: " + e.toString());
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: It depends on the implementation of your `valueEventListener`. Can you share a minimal listener that reproduces the problem. Typically something with a `Log.d` will do the trick. While you're editing, also replace your data structure with the actual JSON from your database (as text, no screenshot). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen
Just updated the listener and JSON format in post, sorry that I cannot share my whole JSON file, but it will looks like that. My first key node would be timestamp.

Comment: Thanks for updating. That helps. One bit I was curious about is this `for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren())`, which you do correctly. I'm just not sure how to read the JSON. Are you just ordering on these two keys from this snippet: `1476986154` and `1477280739`?

Comment: Not only those two keys. In fact, I have 100 keys under that path, then each key has their own map value. The JSON posted above is the first two of them. Everything works fine but it just return the greatest one first :(

Comment: I mostly wondered if the rest of the JSON under those keys is at all relevant to the problem. If not, you should be able to reproduce with a **much** smaller JSON like `{ "1476986154" : true, "1477280739" : true }`. I'll try to reproduce with that.

Comment: Yes, I think we should be able to use that smaller JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the problem.

If I run this snippet of code:

```
myRef.orderByKey().addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {


    public ArrayList<Long> mDataArrayList;

    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (mDataArrayList == null) {
            mDataArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        } else {
            mDataArrayList.clear();
        }

        getDataChange(dataSnapshot);

        System.out.println(mDataArrayList);

    }


    private void getDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
        try {
            for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                long timestamp = Long.parseLong(data.getKey());
                mDataArrayList.add(timestamp);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            System.err.println("onDataChange Exception: " + e.toString());
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException();
    }
});
```

With this JSON:

```
{ "1476986154" : true, "1477280739" : true }
```

It prints:

```
[1476986154, 1477280739]
```

Which seems the correct order to me since `1476986154` < `1477280739`.

Comment: Thank you so much for keeping update.
And yes, I also cannot reproduce this problem if only query with **DatabaseReference.orderByKey()**..so it's really weird.
Have you tried **DatabaseReference.orderByKey().limitToLast(1)** before **orderByKey()**?

Comment: Yes, I have the same result if I do `myRef.orderByKey().limitToFirst(2).addValueEventListener(...`. I don't doubt you have a problem, but it's hard to help if I can't reproduce it from the code you shared. I simply don't see the difference between your and my code, where mine clearly works in my tests. I recommend that you spend some time starting from scratch to set up a so-called [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Best case, you'll discover along the way what's going wrong. Worst case, you'll end with a small, self-contained piece of code+data that allows us to reproduce it.